# When I used the "git stash", it's report that "beyond a symbolic links" error and the command didn't work

Tags: git

The reported file is just a normal document rather than a symbolic link, but the `git stash` command reported that it's beyond a symbolic link, so I can't run this command successfully. What can I do to fix this?

The operating system on my computer is macos, and I try to delete this file, but when I removed it and run `git stash` again, it still reported the same error.

Below is the reported error information.

```
error: 'xxxxxxxxxx' is beyond a symbolic link
fatal: Unable to process path xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Show the *exact series of commands you ran* that produced the error. Was it just `git stash`, for instance, or did you run `git stash some/path/to/name`?

Comment: I just use `git stash` in work root path.

Comment: OK, that indicates some kind of bug. You'll want to gather everything you need for a proper bug report. I've never seen this behavior from `git stash`, but `git stash path/to/some/file` can do it.

Comment: in my case it happens when I ctrl-C a merge that was taking too long